# How to change value based on select item with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select id="curr">
          <option value="usd" selected>USD</option>
          <option value="eur">EUR</option>
          <option value="pnd">pound</option>
</select>
 <span class="price" data-usd="$1,500" data-eur="£1.271" data-pnd="€1.000">$1,500</span>
 <span class="price" data-usd="$1,500" data-eur="£1.271" data-pnd="€1.000">$1,500</span>
 <span class="price" data-usd="$1,500" data-eur="£1.271" data-pnd="€1.000">$1,500</span>
```

I wants if any one choose Eur then price should change to data-eur value.. or whatever they choose that price should update with that data-

Comment: Have you tried something with `$("select#curr").on("change", ....)` ?

Comment: NO not yet.... aany suggestion?

Comment: Yes, try something with `$("select#curr").on("change", ....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#curr').change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $("span.price").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr("data-"+ v))
  })
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#curr').change(function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $("span.price").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).attr("data-"+ v))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="curr">
  <option value="usd" selected>USD</option>
  <option value="eur">EUR</option>
  <option value="pnd">pound</option>
</select>
<span class="price" data-usd="$1,500" data-eur="£1.271" data-pnd="€1.000">$1,500</span>
<span class="price" data-usd="$1,500" data-eur="£1.271" data-pnd="€1.000">$1,500</span>
<span class="price" data-usd="$1,500" data-eur="£1.271" data-pnd="€1.000">$1,500</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write some JS code:

```
const currencySelector = $("#curr");
const elements = $('.price');
const currencies = {
  'usd': 1500,
  'eur': 1.271,
  'pnd': 1000
}

currencySelector.on('change', (event) => {
const value = event.target.value;
  elements.each((index, el) => {
    $(el).html(currencies[value]);
  });
});
```